# Avoid users from editing others data in google docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a public spreadsheet and I want to restrict users from editing what others did write so they can only edit their own posts, is that possible?

Comment: This seems more Super User-y to me.

Answer (score 0):

For anonymous editors that is impossible but if you have users' e-mail addresses, there is a way to specify protected range or sheet for each user.

In Google sheets click Data -> Protected sheets and ranges. It opens a toolbar on the right side of the screen. There you can define desired range to be protected. Give that range a name and click "Set permissions". Now set editing permissions to "Restrict who can edit this range" and from the dropdown list select "Custom" and write editor's e-mail in the box below. Done!